# How to extend polyline of google maps based on gps location latitudes and langitudes dynamically

Tags: ios, google-maps

Initialy  created poly line  and added some path to it . after creating this polyline i need add some other points based on gps location and drawing polyline again .is that redraw again the path.

```
_path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[_path addLatitude:12.9716 longitude:77.5946]; // bangalore
[_path addLatitude:13.3710 longitude:76.6413]; // Fiji
[_path addLatitude:15.3173 longitude:75.7139]; // Hawaii
[_path addLatitude:15.3647 longitude:75.1240]; // Mountain View

GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9716, 77.5946);
marker1.title = @"Bangalore";
marker1.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.2, 0.9);
marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
marker1.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
marker1.snippet = @"India";
marker1.map = _mapView;

GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.3710, 76.6413);
marker2.title = @"Tumkur";
marker2.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.3, 0.9);
marker2.snippet = @"India";
marker2.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
marker2.map = _mapView;

GMSMarker *marker3 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker3.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(15.3173, 75.7139);
marker3.title = @"Mysore";
marker3.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.3, 0.9);
marker3.snippet = @"India";
marker3.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
marker3.map = _mapView;

GMSMarker *marker4 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker4.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(15.3647, 75.1240);
marker4.title = @" Hubli";
marker4.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.3, 0.9);
marker4.snippet = @"India";
marker4.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
marker4.map = _mapView;
marker4.rotation = 180;

CLLocationCoordinate2D circleCenter1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(15.3647, 75.1240);
GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:circleCenter1 zoom:10];
[_mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];

_polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:_path];
_polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
_polyline.strokeWidth = 1.f;
_polyline.map = _mapView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    static CLLocation *lastKnownLocation = nil;

    if(lastKnownLocation == nil) lastKnownLocation = [locations lastObject];
    else
    {
        CLLocation *currentLoc = [locations lastObject];

        // Forming GMSPath from User's last location to User's current location.
        GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath new];
        [path addCoordinate:[lastKnownLocation coordinate]];
        [path addCoordinate:[currentLoc coordinate]];

        GMSPolyline *polyLine = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        polyLine.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        polyLine.strokeWidth = 2.f;
        polyLine.map = googleMap;

        // Saving current loc as last known loc,so that we can draw another GMSPolyline from last location to current location when you recieved another callback for this method.
        lastKnownLocation = currentLoc;
    }
}
```

Above code will draws path on google map when app got new location update(from second time onward).

Hope that helps,

Get back to me if you need some more deep info.

Comment: In your code  every time  GMSMutablePath will create new instance  so that causes memory leak ..thanks for help

Comment: However the GMSMutablePath object is local only & will dies when the else block is finished,if needed can set the path instance to nil after using it.

Comment: One more thing is untill & unless we are using ARC,the code related to GMSMutablePath will not causes any memory leaks,Restructure the code asper your need,i just want to give you an idea about the requirement.